# Lack of blooming effect in iOS 13.0

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, ios13

I want to make blooming effect in arkit by camera settings:

```
self.sceneView.pointOfView.camera.bloomIntensity = 2.0;
self.sceneView.pointOfView.camera.bloomBlurRadius = 30;
self.sceneView.pointOfView.camera.bloomThreshold = 0.6;
```

It works great below iOS 13.0, something like this:

[image]

But when the same code run on the system iOS 13 or newer, it works like this:

[image]

The blooming settings of camera does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to add bloom to a node with this approach.

```
func addBloom() -> [CIFilter]? {
  let bloomFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIBloom")!
  bloomFilter.setValue(10.0, forKey: "inputIntensity")
  bloomFilter.setValue(30.0, forKey: "inputRadius")
  return [bloomFilter]
}
```

Then you can add it to your node like this:

```
myNode.filters = addBloom()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation, in order to use bloom effect in iOS 13 you need, at first, to enable **[wantsHDR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1644101-wantshdr)** instance property for camera (to apply post-processing effects to a scene).

So your code might look like this:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/myScene.scn")!

    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.wantsHDR = true                 // ENABLED
    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.bloomIterationSpread = 10
    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.bloomIterationCount = 3
    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.bloomIntensity = 20
    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.bloomBlurRadius = 3
    sceneView.pointOfView!.camera!.bloomThreshold = 0.5

    sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, but i am already set "wantsHDR = true" and no effect ....

Answer (score 1):

Quite a late answer, but I think you have to disable **rendersCameraGrain** on the SceneView, as having this enabled unfortunately messes with applied SCNTechniques (which afaik are used under the hood to apply effects like Bloom, Saturation, etc…)